# Load Testing with Visual Studio Team Services and distribute load across regions or IPs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing, azure-devops

I am using **VSTS** to create a **Load Test**. Please see the attached screen for configuration details.

When I a run the test on PROD endpoint with a "x" number of user load, PROD server firewall is blocking my requests, assuming its a spam/attacker.

With out altering my firewall, how can I distribute my LOAD from various regions or IP addresses, so that firewall might consider it as real users across the globe.

It looks like there is a option to set the location, but I can only set one location not multiple.

[image]

On the other note, currently I run this test on **VS 2015 Enterprise**, is that the only option? or I can deploy this test to some IIS server and run it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to distribute various regions, you can select one at a time.  Currently any run you execute with VSTS, will use one of the IPs that is assigned to you.

Load testing such application on your PROD server require the load test agents in the Cloud-based Load Testing Service to reach them in a secure way. One way to accomplish this scenario is to use ‘Trusted IP’ as described below. Check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/09/load-testing-applications-behind-firewall-using-trusted-ip/

And besides VS 2015 Enterprise, VS Ultimate 2013 Update 4 or Update 5 is also supported to load test in the cloud.

Comment: this link doesn't explain how to request trusted IPs -
 
Number of IPs you should request depends on the number of concurrent Load Test runs you plan to execute. Concurrent runs are only needed if you have to use more than 20 cores to generate the load.

Comment: Please check the first item and fill in a table send it to vsoloadtest@microsoft.com from the Visual Studio Online account owner’s email ID.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Can you please check the link in this answer. It used to discuss how to request IP addresses from Microsoft but the page appears to have been altered without any mention of that change. Look at the words about *"limited preview"* in the last comment (my comment) on that page. Those words were copied from the original of this article.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cant use multiple locations for a run. But If you want to use multiple IPs for your run, please set "Use Multiple IPs" to true under Run Settings Properties.This works with VS 2015 Update 1
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm whether this works with a cloud based test using Visual Studio Team Services(VSTS)? The 4th FAQ in the link in the answer by  @Cece - MSFT says that one IP address is used per VSTS execution. If your answer is intended to refer to locally executed tests or those from your own controller and agents then please state that clearly.

Comment: The link shared above talks about using Trusted IP which is intended to be used for Applications Behind firewall where the customers need to whitelist these IPs. What I am referring to works with Cloud load test with VSTS when the application is public. Hope I made it clear. Thanks!